# Call Rest API with user using Python requests

Tags: python, django, rest

I want to call an API using requests.get() method where I have to give username and password as authentication like below.

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
```

but I don't want to give password in auth as it will work dynamically where password will be encrypted.

so is there any way to do this by only giving username and not password?

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my question.

Comment: I think you should try and better explain what you want to achieve. You want to make an authenticated API call without the (necessary, I presume)   password ? how does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of methods to authenticate with an API, the most popular would probably be [Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) with something like JWT. This will allow your users to authenticate with your API without sending username and password. If you are using django rest framework, the link I provided should help to get you started.